# popviewcontroller is not calling viewWillappear

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I'm using the following code to display the previous view when a user is clicking on a button

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

In the previous view,  I overwrite  viewWillAppear to initialized few things.  However, it seems like viewWillAppear is not being called.  I put NSLog in viewDidload, viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear and only viewDidAppear is being called.  Is this normal behavior?  If yes, what event should I override so I can do my initialization?  Thank you.

As requested -viewWillAppear for the previous view

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    NSLog(@"ViewWillAppear");
        //[[GameStore defaultStore] resetGame];
        [self setHangmanImage];

    NSLog([[[GameStore defaultStore] selectedList] label]);
        [labelListName setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"List Name: %@", [[[GameStore defaultStore] selectedList] label]]];
        [labelCurrentIndex setHidden:YES];
        [labelCurrentWord setHidden:YES];
        [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO];

        [FlurryAnalytics logEvent:@"GameViewController - viewWillAppear"];

        [self getNewQuestion];

    NSLog(@"ViewWillAppear finish");
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

}
```

I setup the UINavigationalController in the app delegate using the following code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    HomeViewController *hv = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                             initWithRootViewController:hv];

    // You can now release the itemsViewController here,
    // UINavigationController will retain it
    [hv release];

    // Place navigation controller's view in the window hierarchy
    [[self window] setRootViewController:navController];


    [navController release];


    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I don't know what happened but last night after trying to run the app one more time in the simulator and its still having this issue, I decided to save everything and shut my computer down since it was getting late.

This morning I turned my computer back on opened up xcode, clean the project and build and run it and I the problem is fixed and -viewWillAppear is called.  I didn't change anything and its working.  I added NSLog in -willShowView and its not getting called.  I don't know why all of a sudden viewWillAppear is being called.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tried manually calling -viewWillAppear?

Comment: how do i manually call viewWillAppear?  do I call that from the view where I call [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; from?

Comment: Yep - ideally you'd put `[previousView viewWillAppear:YES]` above your `-popViewControllerAnimated:`

Comment: So if manually calling it isn't working then you either have a problem with referencing your previous view, or you're incorrectly overriding `-viewWillAppear:`. Mind posting some of the `-viewWillAppear:` code?

Comment: I am assuming -viewWillAppear for the previous view?

Comment: If this isn't getting called and xs2bush's solution isn't working, then there is most likely something wrong with your `UINavigationController` setup.

Comment: I setup the UINavigationController in the appDelegate, I will add the code op the appDelegate

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure your navigation controller's delegate is set and then use this function to call viewWillAppear in the class whose viewWillAppear you want to call:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController 
      willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [self viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Comment: I did this and the willShowViewcontroller is not being called.

Comment: is the navigation controller's delegate set? does this class have <UINavigationControllerDelegate> in its header?

Comment: yes,  I tried to do it in both the previous view and the view that call the popViewController and its not being called in both place

Answer (score 5):

I've just hit a problem very much the same and after some testing discovered that calling popViewControllerAnimated: in a block (from a network response in AFNetworking) viewDidAppear isn't called in the parent view.
The solution that worked for me here was to call it in the main thread instead.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // If not called on the main thread then the UI doesn't invoke the parent view's viewDidAppear
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I have just hit this problem as well the root cause of this problem is because I put self.navigationController.delegate = self on viewDidLoad. My solution is to put the delegation on viewWillAppear :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   self.navigationController.delegate = self;
}
```

After that popViewController will hit viewWillAppear.